# Data Category Mapping not working properly for knowledge articles

Tags: lightning, case, knowledge, data-category

In my org, the 'knowledge sidebar' section which is visible on opening a Case record should ideally show all the suggested articles based on Data Category mapping.

I have a Data Category Group named 'Test'. I have done a data category mapping with 'Test' Data Category Group and a Case picklist field named 'Type'.Default data category is selected as 'All'. So that suggested articles are shown after filtering with 'Type'and Data Category Test. 
Currently it is displaying Suggested Articles based on the fields mentioned in 'Case fields used to find knowledge articles' in Knowledge settings, like 'Subject'.The articles which are coming in suggested article result are tagged with Test Data Category, even if I never mentioned to filter articles with 'Subject' field and 'Test' Data Category.

It has also been observed that suggested Article based on Type field is also displaying only if, Type field is added in 'Case fields used to find knowledge articles' section. I tried to disable this section as well, but it is not working.

What can I do to ensure that filtering of Suggested Article is only done through Data Category Mapping.